# ¿Como ordenar una lista de tuplas en Python?

Tags: python, lista, ordenamiento

¿Como ordenar una lista de tuplas decreciente con respecto al primer elemento de la tupla y creciente con respecto al segundo en Python?

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que implementar tu propia función `key`, que devuelva un objeto python (puede ser un entero, otra tupla, etc.) en base a la cual se haría la ordenación. Es decir, `sorted()` llamará a tu función `key` para cada elemento de la lista a ordenar, y realizará la ordenación en base a lo que `key` le retorne para cada elemento.

Para este caso particular se me ocurre por ejemplo que la función "key" devuelva una tupla igual a la original, pero con el segundo elemento cambiado de signo. Esto funcionará si las tuplas que manejas son de enteros o reales:

```
def clave_ordenacion(tupla):
  return (tupla[0], -tupla[1])

datos = [ (3, 1), (2, 3), (3, 2), (1, 2), (4, 1), (4,2), (3,3)]
sorted(datos, key=clave_ordenacion)
```

```
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3), (3, 2), (3, 1), (4, 2), (4, 1)]
```

Si las tuplas contuvieran cadenas, o cualquier otro tipo de dato comparable, esta solución ya no serviría. Es un problema interesante.

Resulta sencillo implementar una solución general en Python2, pues en esa versión de Python a la función `sorted()` se le podía pasar un parámetro `cmp` con una función de comparación que recibía dos parámetros a comparar, a y b, y debía retornar un número positivo si `a>b`, negativo si `b<a` o cero si `a==b` (según tu propio criterio de comparación).

En tu caso `a>b` si el primer elemento de `a` es mayor que el primer elemento de `b` o, si los primeros elementos son iguales, cuando el segundo elemento de `a` es menor que el de `b`. Es decir:

```
def cmp_tuplas(a, b):
   if a[0]>b[0]:
      return 1
   elif a[0]<b[0]:
      return -1
   else:
       if a[1]<b[1]:
          return 1
       elif a[1]>b[1]:
          return -1
       else:
          return 0
```

Esta función sirve para cualquier tipo de dato que puedan contener las tuplas, con tal de que se puedan comparar entre sí los primeros elementos. Una función así podía usarse en Python2 con `sorted()`, en la forma siguiente:

```
sorted(datos, cmp=cmp_tuplas)  # Python2 solo!
```

Pero en Python3 se ha eliminado porque la función `key` en teoría puede usarse en cualquier caso donde una `cmp` sea posible, y más.

El caso es que no se me ocurre ninguna forma general de escribir una función `key` que sirva para cualquier tipo de dato que pueda haber en la tupla...

Por suerte Python3 proporciona una utilidad que, dada una función de estilo `cmp` te genera otra de estilo `key`. Lo usaríamos por tanto en la forma siguiente (donde puede verse que funciona también para cadenas y otros mixes):

```
from functools import cmp_to_key
clave_ordenacion = cmp_to_key(cmp_tuplas)

datos = [ (3, 1), (2, 3), (3, 2), (1, 2), (4, 1), (4,2), (3,3)]
datos2 = [("hola", "mundo"), ("que", "tal"), ("hola", "ana"), ("que", "mal"), ("adios", "mundo") ]
datos3 = [("hola", 3), ("que", 2), ("hola", 5), ("que", 7), ("adios", 42) ]

print(sorted(datos, key=clave_ordenacion))
print(sorted(datos2, key=clave_ordenacion))
print(sorted(datos3, key=clave_ordenacion))
```

```
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 3), (3, 2), (3, 1), (4, 2), (4, 1)]
[('adios', 'mundo'), ('hola', 'mundo'), ('hola', 'ana'), ('que', 'tal'), ('que', 'mal')]
[('adios', 42), ('hola', 5), ('hola', 3), ('que', 7), ('que', 2)]
```